# Form can only be submitted with Submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form.  The only way I want the form to be submitted is with the submit button.  I want to ensure that the enter button or go button on ios were not used to submit the form.

Comment: event.preventDefault() is your friend. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

Comment: It shouldn't matter how the request is sent.

Comment: On the server side, check if the name of the button used for submitting isset(). That should work. If its not, then you ignore the post.

Comment: @Zapp I need to stop submitting the form if it wasn't submitted via the Submit button.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Makes for a worse and inconsistent user experience.

Comment: @Roope It's to prevent accidentally submitting a long form on iOS.  I know about jQuery form validation, but that's not how I want to do it.  I just want to  only allow the form to be submitted with the submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The HTML

The `<input type="button">` will not trigger an automatic submit with the enter key or the 'go' button on mobile devices.

```
<form action="my-handler.php" method="POST" id="my_form">

    <label for="some_input">Input 1
    <input name="some_input" id="some_input" type="text">
    </label>

    <label for="another_input">Input 2
    <input name="another_input" id="another_input" type="text">
    </label>

    <input type="button" value="Submit Form" id="submit_button">

</form>
```

#### The JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Stop the form from submitting if enter is pressed
    // or the 'go' button is pressed on mobile
    $( '#my_form' ).submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

    });

    // Submit the form when button is clicked
    $( document ).on( 'click', '#submit_button', function() {

        $( '#my_form' ).submit();

    });

</script>
```

#### Conclusion

You should probably not focus so much on preventing form submission with enter or 'go' on mobile, as this will degrade user experience. I imagine you're doing this because there is something that would be easy to trigger the submission before the form is finished being filled out. Perhaps, in this event form validation is a better friend to you, with something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $( '#my_form' ).submit( function(e) {

        e.preventDefault(); // Don't let the form submit yet

        if( true == validateForm() ) {
            $( '#my_form' ).submit(); // Submit the form
        } else { 
            // Show error output
        }

    });

    // Validation function - returns true or false
    function validateForm() {
        // Do all your field validation and return
        return true;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the button type as button and assign it onclick function

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitform(){
            $('#myform').submit();
        }
    </script>
    <form id="myform" name="myform" action="somepage" method="POST">
        <button type="button" onclick="submitform();"></button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Definitely a good approach, but pressing 'enter' will still submit the form in this case.

Comment: I think it wan't as the type attribute specified as button which will prevent default submit method